# mongorestore with indexing in foreground

Tags: mongodb, restore, indexing

I need to restore huge dump taken with mongodump utility. As the collections are big and mongorestore rebuilds indexes in backround, index building takes very long to finish. What I want is to somehow make mongorestore to build indexes in foreground so that the index building would take less time to finish.

I know I can use `--noIndexRestore` to ignore indexes but then I will have to build indexes one by one, which is a problem again. I am looking for the best way to speed up index building with mongorestore utility.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Only indexes that were created with `{background: true}` originally (and hence have that option set in the `system.indexes` collection) are built in the background once restored.  Once you have the database dumped you will have your data in the `name.bson` file and the metadata (indexes to build) in the `name.metadata.json` file.  Unlike the BSON file, the JSON metadata is just text and can be modified before you restore.

As a test, I created a collection `foo.bar`, with 2 additional indexes besides the default on the `a` field and on the `b` field.  Here is what the dumped `bar.metadata.json` file looked like in the foo folder once I had dumped it out:

```
{ "indexes" : [ { "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "foo.bar" }, { "v" : 1, "key" : { "a" : 1 }, "name" : "a_1", "ns" : "foo.bar" }, { "v" : 1, "key" : { "b" : 1 }, "name" : "b_1", "ns" : "foo.bar", "background" : true } ] }
```

You can "fix" this with your favorite editor and remove `, "background" : true` with a find & replace or similar.  Or you could use a `sed` one liner, something like:

```
 sed 's/, "background" : true//g' bar.metadata.json
```

Which, as expected, gives us:

```
{ "indexes" : [ { "v" : 1, "key" : { "_id" : 1 }, "name" : "_id_", "ns" : "foo.bar" }, { "v" : 1, "key" : { "a" : 1 }, "name" : "a_1", "ns" : "foo.bar" }, { "v" : 1, "key" : { "b" : 1 }, "name" : "b_1", "ns" : "foo.bar" } ] }
```

I tested a restore with the above bar.metadata.json file and my indexes were no longer created in the background, and were not marked as such in `system.indexes` any longer.

Comment: I knew this method. Looks like this is the only way to avoid building indexes in background. Thanks a lot for the confirmation and for the effort to test it.

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work with dumps created using the `--archive` option...

Comment: that option didn't exist when the question/answer was written - I would suggest a new question (probably on the DBA stack exchange) to figure out what it possible with archiving